# Object of abstract class type "CLASSNAME" not allowed?

Tags: c++, header, member

I'm working on a project for my computer science class and just got introduced to classes. I have finished (I think) building the classes I need, but I'm having trouble implementing them. This is what I have for my main.cpp:

```
#include "ElectronicComponent.h"
#include "Resistor.h"
#include "Capacitor.h"
#include "Battery.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_COMPONENTS = 7;
    ElectronicComponent
        *components[NUMBER_OF_COMPONENTS] =
    {
        new Resistor(5.0),     // These are where my errors are.
        new Capacitor(0.0001),
        new Battery(9.0),
        new Resistor(6.5),
        new Battery(11.1),
        new Capacitor(0.000001),
        new Resistor(10000.0),
        /* create more components here */
    };
    return 0;
}
```

And this is an example of one of the classes.

```
#include "ElectronicComponent.h"
class Resistor :
    public ElectronicComponent
{
public:
    Resistor(double);
    virtual ~Resistor();
    virtual double getValue() const = 0;
    virtual std::string getUnits() const = 0;
    virtual std::string to_string() const = 0;
};
```

.

```
#include "Resistor.h"
#include <string>
double value;
std::string units = "Ohm(s)";

Resistor::Resistor(double v)
{
    value = v;
}

Resistor::~Resistor()
{
}

std::string Resistor::to_string() const
{
    return "Resistor value (" + std::to_string(value) + " " + units + ")";
}
```

1. For each item in the **ElectronicComponent** array I should call the **getValue** and **getUnits** member functions and display the results.
2. Go through the **ElectronicComponent** array a second time and display the output using the **ElectronicComponent** item.

Here is an example (assume components is the array of ElectronicComponent
pointers):

```
cout << "Component " << count << " " << *components[index] << endl;
```

The goal is to use the hard-coded numbers to eventually get an output like this:

```
Component 0 Resistor value (5.000000 Ohm(s))
Component 1 Capacitor value (0.000100 Farad(s))
Component 2 Battery value (9.000000 Volt(s))
Component 3 Resistor value (6.500000 Ohm(s))
Component 4 Battery value (11.100000 Volt(s))
Component 5 Capacitor value (0.000001 Farad(s))
Component 6 Resistor value (10000.000000 Ohm(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Resistor`'s (and I assume your other `ElectronicComponent` derived classes) methods should not have the `= 0` at the end of their declaration.

The `= 0` in `virtual double getValue() const = 0;` and `Resistor`'s other methods means the method is a pure virtual function.  That is, it is not implemented and exists only as an interface to be overridden in derived classes.  A class that contains pure virtual methods cannot be instantiated.